# How to deploy index.yaml and update indexes for java app-engine project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Need Help.

I need to delete few indexes which I created extra during the project.

I am not sure how to deploy index.yaml & update my indexes. I am working on Java project on appspot and do not have local environment. I have all my required indexes in datastore-index.xml file ..

I created index.yaml manually and placed under directory
/webapp/WEB-INF/index.yaml  .... it looks something like

```
indexes:

- kind: UserActivityLog
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: createdOn
    direction: desc
```

then i deployed my web app on appstore .. and once application is deployed successfully .. I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=myproject  activated cloud shell .. and typed

```
gcloud datastore indexes cleanup ~/WEB-INF/index.yaml
```

but I am getting error saying

```
**ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.indexes.cleanup) Invalid value for [index_file]: You must provide the path to a valid index.yaml file.**
```

Where is my index.yaml file?  is it deployed when I deployed my application? If yes, how can i find it where it is .. I tried different paths but none worked.

How does this work -- I am really trying to create index.yaml manually per instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying this form https://console.cloud.google.com/ and also from cloud shell environment https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/environment/

Instead of that .. I installed google cloud SDK from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/ and then navigate to directory where index.yaml file is located and then type up following command to update your datastore indexes.

```
gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml
```

Comment: Nice that you found a solution! Would you mind accepting your answer so that it gets a better visibility to other users that may run into a similar issue?

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez accepted my answer, thank you